# daydream controller emulator via usb in unity doesn't work

Tags: usb, daydream

I am trying to run the unity daydream controller demo but I don't get any input from the controller phone when run in the unity editor. It's connected via USB and I've installed all the required libraries. Anyone else have any issues with this? I don't have a Nexus 6p to test on so it has to run via usb in the editor. I'm using unity 5.4.0b18. I tried it on 5.3 as well and get the exact same problem. I've also tried it on two different machines. I get the following 2 errors when run.

```
adb process failed (exit code 127) Check that the Android SDK is installed and that the adb command is in your PATH environment variable.
```

---

```
Error connecting to phone event socket:127.0.1:7003. Connection refused at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connection
```

I think the adb command works because I can go to my sdk directory/platform-tools and do a .adb devices and that works fine.

Any ideas?

Warmest regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

According to the error: "adb process failed..." it seems adb.exe is not in PATH enviroment variable. 
I added the Android sdk\platform-tools directory (where adb.exe is located) into the PATH list and made the trick for me.
I also needed to restart UNITY

Answer (score 0):

I cannot exactly why it is not working. 
But **when I execute Unity.app on terminal**, it works fine.
I don't know it is the unity issue or vr sdk issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a bug, because I fix it plugging the mobile device to the computer.

Maybe it's related with Unity Remote App. When I use it for the first time on a project, it pauses the unity editor if the mobile phone is not plugged.